# How to provide a default implementation for LINQ to SQL's OnValidate method?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, validation, inheritance

I'm trying to implement a validation framework in a base class for [LINQ to SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query#LINQ_to_SQL) entities. The problem I'm having is getting the OnValidate event to fire properly.

The reason is that OnValidate is marked as partial so I can't provide a default implementation in the base class; it gets hidden by a new method declared by the LINQ to SQL class.

How can I fix it so the OnValidate event in the base class will be called automatically?

Example code follows below.

```
public class EntityBase
{
    public bool IsValid
    {
        get { return (GetValidationErrors().Count() == 0); }
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<ValidationError> GetValidationErrors()
    {
        yield break;
    }

    public void OnValidate(System.Data.Linq.ChangeAction action)
    {
        //This never gets fired unless I call explicitly in the derived class.
        if (!IsValid) 
        {
            StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine("Validation errors prevent saving");
            foreach (ValidationError error in GetValidationErrors())
            {
                sb.AppendLine(String.Format("{0}: {1}", error.PropertyName, error.ErrorMessage));
            }
            throw new ApplicationException(sb.ToString());
        }
    }
}

public partial class LinqThingy: EntityBase
{
    public override IEnumerable<ValidationError> GetValidationErrors()
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Name)) yield return new ValidationError("Name required", "Name");
    }

    //Eww nasty, don't want to have to do this.
    partial void OnValidate(System.Data.Linq.ChangeAction action)
    {   
        base.OnValidate(action);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can override the SubmitChanges(ConflictMode) method in your DataContext class. This will ensure that all entities get validated just before they are persisted. This way you won't have to create a custom base class for entities. Here's an example of how to extend the DataContext class:

```
public partial class NorthwindDataContext
{
    public override void SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
    {
        EntityValidator.Validate(this.GetChangedEntities());
        base.SubmitChanges(failureMode);
    }

    private IEnumerable<object> GetChangedEntities()
    {
        ChangeSet changes = this.GetChangeSet();
        return changes.Inserts.Concat(changes.Updates);
    }
}
```

In the example above the custom validation logic goes into the Validate method in the EntityValidator class (you'll have to create it of course).

[This article](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=46) shows how to validate entities in with an O/RM technology such as LINQ to SQL. While it uses Enterprise Library Validation Application Block, the article might be applicable in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a BaseDataContext to inherit from, my example is as follows:

```
public class BaseDataContext : DataContext
{
  // constructor is needed if you have different contexts
    public BaseDataContext(string fileOrServerOrConnection) : base(fileOrServerOrConnection)
    {
    }

    public override void SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
    {
        try
        {
            base.SubmitChanges(failureMode);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
// do whatever you would like with the exception
        }
    }
}
```